# Django, Archery System

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models, calculation

This is more a plea for guidance rather than any hard coding example.
I have set myself a problem to write an archery recording system using Django.
I have got the recording system working well and the system can register users, record their scores, show their scores filtered by round, show the users scores who have shot a particular round etc.
This issue I have got is when it comes to classifying the score.
I will explain:

- In archery scores are recorded against the round you shoot.  These vary so you have 60+ rounds to choose from each having different criteria and different maximum scores.
- Archers are grouped according to gender and age (10 sub groups)
- Archers shoot one of 3 different bowtypes
- The classification system works by taking the round shot and the sub-group that the archer falls into and the bowtype used and looking across a table of values.  The classification gained is the one that the score falls into i.e.
- if you are male and over 18 you are grouped as a 'Gentleman'
- The round you shoot is called a 'York' with a recurve bow and you score 550
- The table you would consult would look like this

Round | 3rd Class | 2nd Class | 1st Class | Bowman | Master Bowman | Grand Master Bowman

```
York     283      511      698       913       1065            1146
```

In this case the classification returned would be 2nd Class.
The tables are quiet extensive as a junior lady could shot the same round but the scores they would need would be different to achieve a similar classification.

My question is can this sort of lookup be done in django?

I have a Scores table that collects the name of the round and the maximum score for that round and also the group that the archer is shooting in.  I have created an index to uniquely identify these variables as there can only be one classification set for a gent shooting a York. What I am trying to do is lookup the appropriate classification table and return the classification value and store it against the round score record.

Here is my Scores model:
class Score(models.Model):

```
BOW_TYPE = (
    ('R', 'Recurve',),
    ('C', 'Compound',),
    ('L', 'Longbow',),
)
archer = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='scores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rndname = models.ForeignKey('Round', related_name='round', verbose_name=("Round Name"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
shootingas = models.ForeignKey('Age', related_name='shootingas', verbose_name='Shooting as', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bowtype = models.CharField(max_length=1, verbose_name=("Bow Type"), choices=BOW_TYPE)
score = models.IntegerField(default='')
dateshot = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date Round Shot", default=timezone.now)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
classindex = models.CharField(max_length =5, default='')

def index(self):
    return str(self.shootingas_id) + str(self.rndname_id) + str(self.bowtype)
index = property(index)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.classindex = self.index  
   super(Score, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.archer) + ' | ' + str(self.score) + ' | ' + str(self.rndname) + ' | ' + str(self.created_date) + ' | ' + str(self.classindex)
```

The Classification table looks like this:

```
class Classification(models.Model):
shootingas = models.ForeignKey('Age', related_name='shooting', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
roundname = models.ForeignKey('Round', related_name='rounds', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bowtype = models.ForeignKey("BowType", verbose_name='bows', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
third = models.IntegerField(default='', verbose_name="3rd Class Bowman", null=True, blank=True)
second = models.IntegerField(default='', verbose_name="2nd Class Bowman",  null=True, blank=True)
first = models.IntegerField(default='', verbose_name="1st Class Bowman",  null=True, blank=True)
BM = models.IntegerField(default='', verbose_name="Bowman",  null=True, blank=True)
MB = models.IntegerField(default='', verbose_name="Master Bowman",  null=True, blank=True)
GMB = models.IntegerField(default='', verbose_name="Grand Master Bowman",  null=True, blank=True)
classindex = models.CharField(max_length=5)

def index(self):
    return str(self.shootingas_id) + str(self.roundname_id) + str(self.bowtype.id)
index = property(index) 

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.classindex = self.index  
   super(Classification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)   

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.index)
```

I need a way of using the classindex in both tables as a link so that the score can be compared against the values in the Classification table and the corresponding classification value, 3rd, 2nd etc, can be returned into the Scores table

I realise this is a bit convoluted but I would really like some pointers as to where I could start to look for a way through this.

If you require any other information please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in Django. It seems as if you're asking for a good way to store these unique scoring tables to compare archers' scores with. Otherwise, with enough logic, you can certainly classify an archer and a score to a certain class.

Django models are representations of SQL fields. This is a fine way to store your scoring tables however you have many options when it comes to storing data.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have a table for the classifications already, it is the linking together and then finding the value.  I have a classindex field consisting of the shootingas.id (the group ie Gentleman etc), the roundname.id, the id of the round ie York = 1 etc) and bowtype.id, (recurve =1) in both tables to link them together, it is how you do this for many possible combinations that is bothering me and where should this calculation be done?  I think the model but not sure how.